# How to change part of a variable/function name in Vim

Tags: vim, neovim, code-editor

I usually have variables/function names like:

```
loginUser()
registerUser()
saveUserData()
checkBaggageTag()
```

So, as you see, some of them repeat the `User` word, and so when I copy paste and need to rename one of them, I do it this way: `loginUser()` I'll do *cw* and write *registerUser*.

Here is the question, is there a way to do *cw* but only change the word up to the first Uppercase letter? (U in User for example) so I can avoid retyping the word User? Of course, I can always do *vtUc* and then type *register* but you know, that's 4 keys...is there a way to it in fewer?

Thanks for your help ^_^

Comment: Forget about counting keystrokes. Whatever nifty saving you may come up with will ultimately be nullified by the amount of keystrokes in your questions, the amount of times you refreshed the page to see if there is a new answer, or a million little things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using command [`t`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#t): <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> (change till the next U).

Using search: <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Searching to the next [upper-case latin letter](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cu) (not only U): <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: OP wants to  change *until* `U`, so that would be `ctU`, not `cfU`.

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely fancy plugins for this (smth. about "motion" and "case"). But on most occasions, IMO, one is able to count, e.g. <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>8</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> etc.